# How can I add a transformer to this transmission line model?

Tags: circuitikz

I hope some knowledgeable `circuitikz` master can help me with this one. I need to add a transformer to `Vl`, but I'm afraid I didn't get the idea of how it actually works. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Transmission line model]

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.0]
   \draw
          (0,0) to [short, o-] (1,0)
          (6,0) to [short, o-] (0,0)
          (6,0) to [open, v_<=$V_{m}$] (6,2) % load voltage
          (5,2) to [short, l=$P_{ml}+jQ_{ml}$, -o] (6,2) % load power

          (0,0) to [open, v^<=$V_{l}$] (0,2) % generator voltage
          (0,2) to [short, o-, l^=$P_{lm}+jQ_{lm}$] (1,2) % generator power
          (1,2) to [C, l^=$j\frac{b_{sh,lm}}{2}$] (1,0) % shunt susceptance
          (1,2) to [R, l=$R_{lm}$] (3,2) % line resistance
          (3,2) to [L, l=$jX_{lm}$] (5,2) % line reactance
          (5,2) to [C, l_=$j\frac{b_{sh,lm}}{2}$] (5,0); % shunt susceptance
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: Welcome! Great you've posted code. Could you complete it to make a compilable small document? It is easier to help if people don't have to figure out which packages and libraries to add to make the code compile. (`circuitikz` is a library or a package? I forget ...)

Comment: Where exactly is the transformer meant to end up? Can you provide an image? (You can even use Paint or something for this.)

Comment: See page 45. I think (but am not sure) that you need to use the anchors from the transformer's nodes to make sure everything else gets lined up correctly.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your much appreciated help. I will make sure next time to add the full working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

All coordinates in MWE are respective to transformer's coordinates ...

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.0]
% transformer
\node[transformer,left=5mm] (T) {};
\draw   
    (T.A1)  to [short, -o] ++ (-0.5,0)
    (T.A2)  to [short, -o] ++ (-0.5,0)
    (T.B1)  to [short, -o] ++ (0.5,0)       coordinate (in+)
    (T.B2)  to [short, -o] ++ (0.5,0)       coordinate (in-)
    (in+)   to [open, v<=$V_{l}$] (in-)                                     % generator voltage
    (in+)   to [short,  l^=$P_{lm}+jQ_{lm}$] ++ (1.5,0)     coordinate (c1+)% generator power
            to [short,C,l_=$j\frac{b_{sh,lm}}{2}$] (c1+ |- in-)             % shunt susceptance
    (c1+)   to [R, l=$R_{lm}$]  ++ (1.5,0) % line resistance
            to [L, l=$jX_{lm}$] ++ (1.5,0) coordinate (c2+)                 % line reactance
            to [short, l=$P_{ml}+jQ_{ml}$, -o] ++ (1.5,0)   coordinate (out+)
%
            to [open, v^<=$V_{m}$] (out+ |- in-)            coordinate (out-)% load voltage
    (c2+)   to [C, l_=$j\frac{b_{sh,lm}}{2}$] (c2+ |- in-)   % shunt susceptance
%
    (out-)  to [short,o-] (in-); % shunt susceptance
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Zarko for nailing it. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LeonardoMartins, I'm glad that answer help you. If you (so) liked answer,  you can accept it (click on check-mark on the top left side of answer) :-)